# HTML files from public folder embedded within an <iframe> do not render in deployed react app

Tags: reactjs, vite, github-pages

I have created a react app with vite. Within my public folder there are advertising campaigns in HTML files in the directory "./public/campaigns/porsche-traffic/file_name".

I am trying to embed these files within an iframe in my main webpage. When I view the code locally, it displays the HTML files from the campaigns folder, however when I deploy the code to gh pages it cannot access the HTML files it needs to.

How can I fix this?

the iframe code is below:

```
<iframe
  onLoad={(e) => {
    const iframe = e.target as HTMLIFrameElement
    if (iframe.contentDocument) {
      setCreative(iframe.contentDocument)
    }
  }}
  id="iframe"
  src={`./campaigns/${selectedCampaign}/${selectedSize}-${selectedCampaign}.html`}
/>
```

I have noticed that trying to view the HTML files in the public folder in my gh repo results in an "Error loading page". Does this mean it is not pushing correctly to gh or should I not be using the public folder for this?